# Animation in css after seeing an object

Tags: html, css, css-animations

All animations on the page load with page refresh.

I would like to get the effect that only after seeing the object on the screen does the animation begin to load. BUT NO REFRESHING THE PAGE

I've seen similar questions, but I'm interested in a way that works only with CSS because I'm still learning and I haven't started learning JS yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do that without JavaScript, also i advise you to quickly jump to learning JS (ofc, after finishing the basics of HTML & CSS, which will take maximum of 1 month).

there is a lot you can do with JavaScript which you can't without.